# How do I write my own function with AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

If I want to write a function, what's the syntax for doing that?  I can't find it anywhere in the documentation?

I just want to take a bunch of code and store it inside a function that can be called, just as I would with any other programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in AMPScript.  This is how I created a pseudo-function using AMPScript and XML [**here on my blog**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/).

The `@productPos` variable value is the input and the content area is the function.  The XML facilitates.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot.  It's one of the limitations of the language.  You can with our SSJS engine, and put AMPscript in your SSJS call, but its pretty hack-ish.  Not to say I haven't done it though!

Hope this helps!